# Unable to make a button that will transition you to main menu with Spritekit Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm  new to Swift and Spritekit and having trouble with implementing a button or imagebutton that will take you to the main menu from the GameScene. All I want to do is to make a button that will display a dialog that will tell you if you want to return to the main menu.

For example is there a way to make a dialog that will transition you to other scenes with the code below?

```
let skview = self.view as! GameSKView!
skview.score = score
let scene = MainMenuScene(size: self.size)
let tr = SKTransition.revealWithDirection(SKTransitionDirection.Down, duration: 1)
scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFill
skview.presentScene(scene,transition: tr)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    func changeScene() {
        let newScene = MainMenuScene(size: self.size)
        let theTransition = SKTransition.revealWithDirection(SKTransitionDirection.Down, duration: 1)
        newScene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
        scene?.view?.presentScene(newScene, transition: theTransition)
    }
```

Comment: Well, it seems your solution is just a function. The problem I want to solve is how to use or create a dialog that will transition me to main menu.  For example how will I use a changeScene() from a popup dialog or something?

Comment: @user3867627 Ah my mistake I misread your question. well I don't know if there is anything like a dialog built into spritekit, you could use your own button image, or use an SKShapeNode and implement the code when the user taps the button.

Answer (score 0):

Currently developing a button that works like a uibutton using spritekit. Here is what I have, it may be slightly overkill for what you want but here it is.https://github.com/marcJV/SKAToolKit/tree/swift?files=1

It will be pulled over to SKAToolKit when as we are porting it to swift. There is also an example project showing off how to use it. Also there is a lack of a proper readme at this point, but the example should have everything you need. This is using swift 2.0